# Internal NuGet Package Management In Large Solutions

Tags: git, visual-studio, version-control, nuget, teamcity

When we started our latest project (large framework), we started out with ProGet for our package server and TeamCity for build (Visual Studio Team Services is the SC). One of the solutions in the framework contains nearly 60 libraries of our code implementing everything from redis to wrappers for external APIs and common models. Each of these libraries are a nuget package. Early on in the project it was very easy to make a change in a core library, check it in, TeamCity would build and push to proget and a quick update and you were off and running.

Shortly though this became unmanageable and the team decided that while under development, no nuget packages in the common library solution would reference each other via their package but rather they would be direct references. This of course quickened the pace of development but had a nasty side effect on the consuming apps. Although the common libraries were direct references, the 7 major pieces of the microservice framework (web api, multiple mvc and some worker roles) when updating any of our internal packages would get multiple copies of the same core libraries which all of the other libs depend on.

For example, there is a single lib named "core" which has the building blocks for which almost everything is built upon in the common libraries. It has many interfaces, etc... Well since all of the other libs consume it directly, they all get a copy of core in their output directly and even more concerning is that our teamcity server handles the versioning for us so not only do they each have a copy of core but its version matches that of the nuget package consuming it.

While not great, this is still not the crux of the problem. During nuget updates in the consuming apps, each library within the app might reference a different version of core depending on the order in which the packages where updated which occasionally leads to build errors and a hunt for the rogue reference.

Now that the project is entering the final phase I want to solve this permanently but I am not sure how.

To have the nuget packages consume each other as nuget packages, a single update could take hours as one dependent package gets updated, you rebuild, it produces another nuget package which a package higher up in the chain requires, etc...

Versioning however is critical as when breaking changes are introduced we want to leverage the nuget dependencies to prevent upgrades where needed.

Has anyone else run into this and solved it? It seems like it would be fairly common if nuget is embraced fully by any development team producing a sizable project.

**Update:**

Example of what is happening under the hood.

CoreLib (interfaces, etc...)
Lib1 (references Corelib directly, current version = v1.0.17)
Lib2 (references Corelib directly, current version = v1.0.99)

Both Lib1 and Lib2 are nuget packages. An update is made to Lib1 which includes a non-breaking change to CoreLib. When Lib1 is checked in, TeamCity kicks off a build and a new nuget package is created, v1.0.18).

When Lib1's package is updated in the consuming projects, Lib1's copy of CoreLib, also v1.0.18 because AssemblyVersion is managed by TeamCity) is of a lower version than Lib2's version (v1.0.99), even though it is a version behind.

The end goal is to get all of these interdependent packages to rebuild, update and repackage themselves but how to do this automatically is really escaping me.

Comment: You mentioned that "During nuget updates in the consuming apps, each library within the app might reference a different version of core depending on the order in which the packages where updated ". As far as I know, if we reference the package projects directly, when we build the entire solution, all projects in this solution will be rebuild, which will not lead to the different version that referenced project dlls. Could you share the detailed steps about how do you reference nuget, update nuget and build your solution?

Comment: Can you combine the core libraries into one solution which is built as a unit but still produces individual packages?  The more core libraries you consolidate like this the quicker the new versions should propagate.

Comment: @Andy All of the nuget packages are individual projects in a single large solution. The issue however comes from the package having dependencies on other projects within the solution.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow; you just do the references in the project file as you would normally.  In the .nuspecs file, also make sure to add a depedency onto the package.  If it requires a certain minimum version, use $version$ in the version attribute for the package dependency.  Assuming of course all assemblies in the solution use the same version.

Comment: @Wendy-MSFT Sorry for the delay, I am just getting back to this. I have updated the question above. The only projects directly referenced are 4 model only libraries (out of the 60). When one of the nuget packages also has a reference to the same models lib, it will include it in the package and it will overwrite the "project references" with the nuget references for the same lib, necessitating to removal of the 4 references, browse and add proj references again. This is a minor irritation in projects with 1 or 2 libs, but our API has 11 and nuget packge solution updates are a dreaded task.

Comment: @Andy See above, the issue is that each nuget package has a different version, as they should. Some get updated regularly, others might not be updated for months or ever after initial creation.

Comment: Is CoreLib also a Nuget package?  It should be for this to work.  Assuming your Nuget packages are artifacts of the build configuration which builds them (lib1.nuget is an artifact of Lib1's build configuration), you can setup an artifact dependency (that is, Lib1's build configuration has an artifact dependency on CoreLib's build artifacts).  You can then use this as a trigger to cause Lib1 and Lib2 to rebuild if their dependencies change.

Comment: And re-reading your question, this problem seems to be a result of the direct references.  Go back to Nuget, and you'll have to wait for the builds to complete and trigger other builds.  Certainly sounds like the time saved using direct references is canceled out by these other issues.

Comment: @Andy I do not disagree. What I am struggling with is the automation of a check in, lets say for CoreLib or even Lib 1 then kicking off a build, updating (not restoring) its nuget packages, then building the resultant lib(s) which would then in return produce the final nuget package. To build on that, TeamCity can perform nuget updates as well as restores however the updates are across the board and cannot be scoped to a particular repository which means 3rd party packages will be updated and that is a non-starter.

Comment: Could you have a script set before the restore that does targeted updates on only your 1st party libraries?  Or alternately, changes the minimum allowed version in packages.config for your 1st party dependencies to be the latest version?

Comment: @Andy Running the update, committing and pushing are certainly options, a bit to maintain but doable until you start getting into the second and third tiers.

For example, Lib3 has nuget to Lib2 and Core, Lib2 has nuget to Lib1 and Core. A change is made in Lib1. This would require:

Lib1 detects a change, builds its new nuget package. 

Lib2 detects that Lib1 has built a new package, it updates/commits the change, produces its package.

Lib3 detects that Lib2 has built a new nuget package, it updates/commits the change, produces its packge.

Comment: But if everything depends on the base CoreLib, this exactly what needs to happen, is it not?  You can't fundamentally change the foundation of a skyscraper without expecting to impact the above floors.  If everything is done in terms of Nuget packages, I think there's a trigger that will cause a build if TC detects new versions of dependent packages.

Comment: @JamesLegan did you ever find a solution for this?  We find ourselves in a very similar spot.  Some suggest sticking to NuGets for "inter-library" dependencies, while others propose direct project references.  We have 1 solution with about 60 projects within, which should each theoretically be a NuGet package.

Answer (score 1):

Project references within a single solution is preferable to creating and publishing intermediate nuget packages and consuming them.

Nuget packages are an excellent way to manage versioning of "intermediate" artefacts when you have more than one solution.  You can have more than one solution for a number of reason but a common reason is when you have multiple development teams.

Assuming you have an internal nuget server set up.  A Visual Studio solution will not allow you to have circular references, the compiler will pick that up.  Thus you need to carefully manage all your dependencies in the nuspec files for those dependencies that are not covered via a project reference within a solution.

A useful reference to the syntax of nuget package versioning is [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/package-versioning).

Comment: If you have 60 projects within a single solution, and you want to publish each project individually as a NuGet package, what would your approach be?  Please keep in mind that there are projects which depend on other projects within those 60 ones.